# Free barcode and QR code scanner app

Tags: gratis, ios, iphone-app, barcode

I'm looking for a free barcode and QR code scanner app like [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) but **for iOS**. I'm not looking for a shopping assistant!

It should

- be able to scan different types of **barcodes and QR codes**
- **suggest reasonable actions** depending on the type of code (like opening a URL in browser, adding a contact …)
- be **gratis and free of ads**
- store scanned codes in a history

---

I tried following apps but both didn't meet the above requirements:

[Quick Scan](https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/id446067710?mt=8) does not seem to handle QR codes at all.

[barcoo](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/barcoo-barcode-scanner-qr/id339525465?mt=8) seems to be more about shopping, didn't know what to do with a QR code containing an URL. Is also not free of ads.

Comment: What about [Barcode Scanner](https://f-droid.org/app/com.google.zxing.client.android)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'm looking for a iOS app. Will be editing my post to highlight that...

Comment: Quick scan does have a qr reader https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quick-scan-qr-code-reader/id483336864?mt=8

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but having one app for scanning barcodes and another for scanning qr codes sounds kinda unconforatble.

Comment: For Android users who might stumble upon this question, [Binary Eye](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.markusfisch.android.binaryeye/) is simply the best.

Answer (score 0):

iHandy offers two apps, one for QR codes and one for Barcodes. They are both free, have a history of scanned codes, and offer reasonable actions after scanning. Here are the links into the Apple AppStore:

https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/qr-code-scanner/id483336864
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quick-scan-qr-code-reader/id483336864

Answer (score 0):

Try the app "i-nigma". I'm happy with this app for many years and there's a good scanning history function.

Disclaimer: I'm not related to the app developers.

Answer (score 0):

QR Scanner is a popular app for ios devices. It is available from the app store and is free. There is a $2 option to remove ads. It runs on both iPhone and iPad.  An older app which was my 1st barcode scanner is RedLaser. Not in app store but still available elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesnt really fit all your requirements, recent versions of iOS (at least the last 2 or 3 major versions now) support [scanning QR codes from the camera app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208843). However, I don't think this supports saving a history of scanned codes.

For barcodes, I use https://apps.apple.com/us/app/barcode-scanner-qr-scanner/id1210662415. I don't remember if it has ads since its been a while since I last used it, but it should support barcodes, QR codes, and saving a history while being free.